# mounted folder permission using fstab cannot be changed

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab

When I mount a CD using an entry in fstab,

```
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom auto noauto,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

a folder /media/cdrom is created with only read permission ( There is no way one can enter the directory using a shell ) because I guess execute is missing.

However strangely, I can enter inside the directory using a file manager like Thunar and read the contents in the directory. The content which is a single avi file can only be read as root.

The whole thing works flawless, with CDs with multiple folders ( like a VCD ). The folder /media/cdrom is created with user rights and with full permissions. Even the contents of the folders inside the CD are accessible by the user.

The problem occurs for CDs where there is only 1 file inside the CD. This maybe technically a foolish statement, but this is my observation so far.

So, to sum it up I have 3 questions:

1. Why is a directory created by fstab with such strange permissions i.e without execute?
2. Why is the content of the mounted CD only accessible to root, althouth I have mentioned the uid and gid in fstab.
3. Why does some CDs work ( see above )  and some does not?